# Async loading of things in .bash_profile - is it even possible?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, git

I've got these absolutely delicious bash scripts in my `.bash_profile` that makes working with git on the command line genuinely pleasant.

```
source ~/dev/git-completion.bash
source ~/dev/git-flow-completion.bash
```

Only problem is that they require a lot of disk IO (and some CPU) work to work. Every time I `cd` into a git repo directory (on an uncached disk) there's an annoying delay that can sometimes last for several seconds.

9/10 times I don't need the info in the prompt immediately. Often I just want to start a terminal, do some stuff and close it.

Would it be possible to make it run as a background task? I.e. asynchronously. That way the heavy blocking IO work could be done whilst I'm doing something else. If I need it immediately after opening a terminal I'm happy to wait. Like I have to do today.

A dream would be something like this:

```
source --async ~/dev/git-completion.bash
source --async ~/dev/git-flow-completion.bash
```

Answer (score 1):

What do the scripts do? Do they set environment variables up or do they just do some on-disk stuff that's environment independent?

If the former, then your luck is probably out: I don't believe it is possible to run a script asynchronously and have it affect the current environment. If the latter, then have you just tried doing `~/dev/git-completion.bash &` ?

Comment: It needs to change my PROMPT eventually. I'll try it and see how it fails but I was hoping for something more sophisticated.